# Чи правильно вживати активний дієприкметник у цьому випадку?

Tags: дієприкметники

Чи правильно написати: *Іванова, проживаючого ...*?

Чи тільки: *Іванова, який проживає...*?

Comment: У цьому контексті краще підходить дієслово _[мешкати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50943&page=1616)_ — але питання залишається: «Іванов, мешкаючий за такою адресою» чи «Іванов, що мешкає за такою адресою».

Comment: на мій непрофесійний погляд, обмеження на дієприкментики активної форми теперішнього часу в українській мові збіднює ії. Тобто, форма існує в принципі, але не для всіх дієслів, і слід знати для яких можна і для яких не можна. Це робить мову негнучкою. Зайві правила будуть з часом відкинуті. Позиції мовознавців стосуються минулого мови - тіх часів, коли мова була менш вживаною, ніж нині або завтра. Мова мусить і буде розвиватися. Прийдуть нові мовознавці та закріплять нові правила. Імхо.

Comment: Особисто я з Вами згоден (як не дивно; мені теж здається, що це радше вада, що збіднює мову). Але тут (на цьому підсайті) прийнято писати відповіді, покладаючись на щось, на якісь книги/словники/джерела. Тому, боюся, Вашу відповідь можуть сприйняти негативно.

Comment: Це питання є дублікатом.

Answer (score 6):

[Мова- ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/dieprukmetnuku-iz-zakinchennyamu-achuj,-yachuj,-uchuj,-yuchuj-vzhuvatu-chu-ni)

> Йдеться про дієприкметники, що закінчуються на -ачий, -ячий, учий,
> -ючий (бачачий, спляча, слабнучий, читаючий). Більшість мовознавців, зокрема Олена Курило, Борис Антоненко-Давидович, Юрій Шевельов,
> Олександр Пономарів, Святослав Караванський, радили й радять уникати
> їх, оскільки вони є невластивими українській мові.

[Дієприкметники із закінченнями -ачий, -ячий, -учий, -ючий: словничок](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/dieprukmetnuku-iz-zakinchennyamu-achuj,-yachuj,-uchuj,-yuchuj-slovnuchok)

> подорожуючий --- який подорожує, подорожній і мандрівник

За аналогією, краще написати *"Іванов, який проживає..."*

Comment: На мою думку, у цьому випадку буде навіть краще замінити дієприкметник на прикметник: "Іванов, мешканець...".

Answer (score 2):

Погляди різних мовознавців на активні дієприкметники різняться: дехто зовсім відмовляє їм у праві бути частиною української мови, дехто приймає лише ті, що більш-менш укоренилися (є в словниках), а інших намагається уникати. Загалом мовознавці сходяться в тому, що активні дієприкметники не дуже властиві українській мові, але хтось сприймає це  суворіше, а хтось м'якіше.

Оскільки я не бачу *проживаючий* у жодному словнику — навіть у тих, що містять інші слова на *-ачий*, *-ячий*, *-учий*, *-ючий* (наприклад: *бажаючий*, *оточуючий*, *функціонуючий* — які, однак, теж не бездоганні й оточені суперечками), зокрема ані в [«Словнику української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/), ані в [«Словниках України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) — я б наполегливо рекомендував використовувати варіант «що проживає» / «який проживає».

P.S.: Сказане в попередньому абзаці стосується й дієслова *мешкати* — жоден відомий мені словник не містить слова *мешкаючий*, тому я наполегливо раджу вживати «що мешкає» / «який мешкає», а не *мешкаючий*.